# Data retrieving by Latitude longitude matching from both tables in mysql

Tags: sql, wildcard, sql-like, query-performance

I have two tables are A & B.
A table having columns are hotelcode_id, latitude,longitude
B table having columns are latitude, longitude

Requirement is, I need retrieving hotelcode_id according to match latitude from both tables and longitude from both tables

I have designed the following query, but still in query performance

```
SELECT a.hotelcode_id, a.latitude,b.latitude,b.longitude,b.longitude
FROM A 
JOIN B
ON a.latitude like concat ('%', b.latitude, '%') AND a.longitude like concat ('%', b.longitude, '%')
```

Also I'm designed the following another query but I can't able to accuret data's.

This query running too much time but still now I can't able to retrieve the data's.

NOTE:

- A table has 150k records
- B table has 250k records

: I have set DECIMAL(10,6) for latitude and longitude columns in both tables.

I have done the following job but still in problems in query performance,

- done index properly using EXPLAIN statements
- done hash partition for this tables

I think wild card characters not allowed the index reference.

Also LIKE SELECT query performance very poor in MySQL.

Any other solution is there instead wild cards issues & LIKE issues in SELECT query?

Comment: I am challenging your strategy a bit ... is it true for your data that in both tables LON and LAT are so equal that your join will work?

Usually when matching geo data you would see if a LON/LAT is not more than x angle second/mins/degrees away from the target LON/LAT or the distance bewetween 2 points is less than y m/km/NM/...

Comment: Yes mikd. This is true data in both tables. My join query working. But, this join query taking too much time. I can't able to retrieve data's till now. Please help me mike!

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the numeric values of LAT/LON pairs are equal across the two table, the simple approach would be

```
SELECT a.hotelcode_id, a.latitude,b.latitude,b.longitude,b.longitude
FROM A JOIN B
WHERE a.latitude = b.latitude
AND   a.longitude = b.longitude
```

If there is some inaccuracy in the data, you may want to define the maximum deviation (here 3.6 angle seconds) which you would regard as "same place", e.g.

```
SELECT a.hotelcode_id, a.latitude,b.latitude,b.longitude,b.longitude
FROM A JOIN B
WHERE ABS(a.latitude-b.latitude) < 0.001
AND   ABS(a.longitude-b.longitude) < 0.001
```

Mind that in the second case the actual distance (in km) between two points are not the same at any given LAT ... higher LAT --> less distance

And review the sizing of LON and LAT columns ... you know that (usually ...)

- -180 <= LON <= 180
- -90 <= LAT <=  90